# Minecraft Bukkit - Custom GUI when right click on a villager

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm making a [Bed Wars][1] plugin for my *Minecraft* server. Actually I have to make a custom villager shop.

I have made my GUI (with implements InventoryHolder). It's working with a commands. I have searched all over the Internet, but I have not found anything on a system that makes, when you right click on a villager (I know how to spawn it) it's is showing my GUI. What would be an idea for that?

edit :  I tried to use PlayerInteractAtEntityEvent, i maked a class, register it and make this code :

```
    @EventHandler
    public void interactAtEntity(PlayerInteractAtEntityEvent e) {
        if (e.getRightClicked() == ShopVillager.villager1) {
            System.out.println("UwU");
            Player player = e.getPlayer();
            FastShop shop = new FastShop(player);
            player.openInventory(shop.getInventory());
            e.setCancelled(true);
            return;
        }
    }
```

It show the gui like 0.2sec but after i close it and show the original trade gui, and i got the uwu in my console.

Comment: Makes what when you right click? Shop? Can you make it clearer? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69781718/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just go on github and i have explore a lot of bedwars plugin code, and i find !!!

I just need to use : `PlayerInteractEntityEvent`

Thats it

Answer (score 0):

It depend of how you make the PNJ (villager).

1. Spawn PNJ as default entity

If you spawn it with `world.spawnEntity`, you can use default spigot event.

For example, with `PlayerInteractAtEntityEvent`, you can get the entity.

2. Spawn entity with Packet

Personnally, I used packet to detect `PacketPlayInUseEntity` and get villager with the ID.

3. Globally, with multiple interact event and by checking location/nearest PNJ, you will be able to find the which one you are looking for.

Comment: I tried this code : ```        if (e.getRightClicked() == ShopVillager.villager1) {
            System.out.println("UwU");
            Player player = e.getPlayer();
            FastShop shop = new FastShop(player);
            player.openInventory(shop.getInventory());
            return;
        }```
It's say Uwu but the gui show like 0.2sec and switch automaticly on the realy gui

Comment: You should cancel the event to prevent default action

Comment: already did and don't work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have greater versatility and use things other than villagers, consider using the Citizens2 API, which lets you easily spawn entities and attach traits to them.

- https://wiki.citizensnpcs.co/API

#### Adding Citizens to your Maven project

```
    <repository>
        <id>everything</id>
        <url>https://repo.citizensnpcs.co/</url>
    </repository>
```

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.citizensnpcs</groupId>
        <artifactId>citizens-main</artifactId>
        <version>VERSION</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

#### Custom Shop NPC

You can spawn an NPC, and attach a custom Trait to it. [Here's how I implemented it in a minigame I made](https://github.com/TheKingElessar/Assault/blob/master/modules/source/src/com/thekingelessar/assault/game/world/map/ItemShopTrait.java):

```
public class ItemShopTrait extends Trait
{
    public ItemShopTrait()
    {
        super("itemshoptrait");
    }
   
    
    @EventHandler
    public void rightClick(net.citizensnpcs.api.event.NPCRightClickEvent rightClickEvent)
    {
        if (rightClickEvent.getNPC().equals(this.getNPC()))
        {
            this.openShop(rightClickEvent.getClicker());
        }
    }
    
    @EventHandler
    public void leftClick(net.citizensnpcs.api.event.NPCLeftClickEvent leftClickEvent)
    {
        if (leftClickEvent.getNPC().equals(this.getNPC()))
        {
            this.openShop(leftClickEvent.getClicker());
        }
    }
    
    public void openShop(Player player)
    {
        // Open shop inventory, etc.
    }
}
```

And then to spawn the NPC and attach the trait:

```
Location shopLocation = /* Location where you want the NPC to spawn */;

// shopList is an ArrayList of usernames that have skins you want to use. This randomly chooses one of the skins from the list.
Random random = new Random();
String randomName = MapBase.shopList.get(random.nextInt(shopList.size())); 

// EntityType.PLAYER can be changed to whatever EntityType you want, like a VILLAGER
// "Shop" is the name of the NPC
NPC npc = CitizensAPI.getNPCRegistry().createNPC(EntityType.PLAYER, "Shop");

// Sets the NPC's skin to always stay the same
npc.data().setPersistent(NPC.PLAYER_SKIN_UUID_METADATA, randomName);

// Add the right/left click traits to the NPC
npc.addTrait(new ItemShopTrait());

// No capes
SkinLayers trait = npc.getTrait(SkinLayers.class);
trait.hideCape();
trait.setVisible(SkinLayers.Layer.CAPE, false);

// Spawn the NPC in the world
npc.spawn(shopLocation);
```

Comment: I don't use maven, is a way to implement it without a pom.xml?